Update Powershell 7 to specific version without winget
I have a server running Powershell 7.3.10 core and I need to upgrade to 7.4.2 which is the latest version my company supports. The problem is the server doesn't have winget on it and I can't find an .msi or .zip to download. How can I update to 7.4.2 specifically? Core isn't a requirement, it's a full gui Windows 2019 v1809 server.

I found the direct link to the msi.
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.4.2/Powershell-7.4.2-win-x64.msi
btw, you can do this for any version. Just replace the x's with what version you want
https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v7.x.x/Powershell-7.x.x-win-x64.msi
